# Async getJSON with knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I'm trying to call a JSON result in my HTML with Knockout.JS with following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var submissionViewModel = new SubmissionModel();
submissionViewModel.getSubmission().done(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(submissionViewModel, document.getElementById("submission"));
  })
});

var SubmissionModel = function () {
var self = this;
self.Submission = ko.observable(null);

self.getSubmission = function () {

    $.getJSON('/Submission/GetSubmission',
        function (data) {
            self.Submission = ko.mapping.fromJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    );
  }
}
```

For starters I'm fairly new with the Knockout JS lib so bear with me. From what I can get is that my applybindings is happening before my JSON is loaded into the Submission property.

I tried putting the thread to bed and started rocking the cradle but that resulted in following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding text: function (){return (). } Message: Cannot read property  of null

I get what's happening and that I need to halt the execution of the `$(document).ready` code untill the JSON call is completed. I tried to achieve this with the `.done` function in jQuery but that resulted in the following error

> Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

As I am not that experienced in knockout could any of you guys point me in the right direction ?

Comment: you can alternatively do a lazy load check this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26523/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code seems fine. In your `self.getSubmission` function, return the promise object like

```
self.getSubmission = function () {

    return $.getJSON('/Submission/GetSubmission',
        function (data) {
            self.Submission(ko.mapping.fromJSON(JSON.stringify(data)));
        }
    );
  }
```

'done' is undefined because you are not chaining it with javascript promise object.

Comment: That issue is solved now thanks. Now to figure out why isn't showing in the HTML

Comment: use `self.Submission(//your value)` not `=` convention . cheers